# Poland : Effects of Negative Decision of Temporary Residence application on Future Schengen Visas

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, poland

i work as Software Engineer in a startup company in Warsaw, Poland. Back in 2018, i approached agent at Biggroup(https://bigroup.biz/en/) and we made application for Temporary Residence Permit(Karta Pobytu) in Warsaw .After almost 1 year of waiting (Seems this is very normal in Warsaw) ,i got negative decision for my application(Reason is stated below) on June 2019 and we made appeal for decision immediately. it is almost 6 months now and i did not receive any reply from Poland foreigners office for my appeal so far.Currently i have only red stamp given by foreigners office confirming successful submission of necessary documents in my passport.

i am helpless and dont know what i should do now, my agent(one who submits application on behalf of me) keeps saying i need to wait and wait for past 1.5 years and its totally hopeless ,so i have decided to go back to India.Currently i have only red stamp in my passport.

[image: stamp given by foreigners office confirming submission of necessary documents]

1. Will there be any issues in Immigration check ?
2. will this affect my future visa application?

i am thinking to apply for universities in Europe. i am afraid if this negative decision from one of Schengen area will affect any of my future visa application to any Schengen Zone.

Reason for Denial of Temporary Residence Permit :

"After analyzing the evidence gathered in the case, it should be stated that, despite the precise specification of the type of documents required in the summons and the properly served summons, the Party has not provided the documents necessary to issuing a decision in accordance with her request.The administrative body informed that if documents were not delivered within the specified time limit, the decision would be taken on the basis of evidence gathered in the case. It should be noted that a photocopy of the premises lease agreement, a photocopy of confirmation of residence and a photocopy of a certificate of insurance attached to the case file, not confirmed for compliance with the original, do not constitute evidence in administrative proceedings within the meaning of the Code of Administrative Procedure. Photocopies of documents have no evidential value. "
(we appealed the decision as is not true , when we made the application the house contract was valid and then it got expired. We did not submit the renewed house contract as i had no idea and the attorney who handled my application did not say anything about it.We made appeal providing the necessary documents but there is no reply from foreigners office yet)

Comment: 'red stamp' tells us nothing. Without given reason for denial, no realistic advice can be given. There can be reasons that have nothing to do with you as an individual, so not stating the reason is not helpful.

Comment: @MarkJohnson red stamp is given in Poland which confirms the Successful submission of all the necessary documents for Temporary residence permit

Comment: @Since you have started an appeal, I would notify them that you are leaving so that the appeal can be cancelled. Ask for confirmation in writing which would avoid any problems when leaving.

Comment: @MarkJohnson i will definitely do this. Will this affect my future visa application anyways?. I am planning to do Masters in Germany. I am afraid if this will affect someway

Comment: Without know the reason, no answer can be given. It will only effect other applications if the polish enter a negative entry into the SIS system.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Reason for Denial :

Not submitting original copy of House contract. (This is not true , when we made the application the house contract was valid and then it got expired. We did not submit the renewed house contract as i had no idea and the attorney who handled my application did not mention anything about it.We made appeal stating the information but there is no reply from foreigners office yet)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102413/discussion-between-aranganathan-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have started an appeal, I would notify them that you are leaving so that the appeal can be cancelled.

Ask for confirmation in writing which would avoid any problems when leaving.

This refusal will only effect other applications if the polish enter a negative (in the sence of **serious**) entry into the SIS system.

> Reason for Denial : Not submitting original copy of House contract.

I doubt this would be a reason for a negative  SIS entry.

Comment: That was reason given to me by my Attorney representative  

Exact decision was in polish. i just translated , it says 


// "After analyzing the evidence gathered in the case, it should be stated that, despite the precise specification of the type of documents required in the summons and the properly served summons, the Party has not provided the documents necessary to  issuing a decision in accordance with her request."

Comment: The administrative body informed that if documents were not delivered within the specified time limit, the decision would be taken on the basis of evidence gathered in the case.  It should be noted that a photocopy of the premises lease agreement, a photocopy of confirmation of residence and a photocopy of a certificate of insurance attached to the case file, not confirmed for compliance with the original, do not constitute evidence in administrative proceedings within the meaning of the Code of Administrative Procedure.  Photocopies of documents have no evidential value.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for information about hopeless karta pobytu application in warsaw

https://www.mexicanosenpolonia.com/2019/02/the-struggle-of-applying-for-residence-permit-in-poland/

[image]

Comment: The video contained in the above link is well worth watching (observe the faces of the characters closely)! Original facebook link: [When you go to immigration office in Poland](https://m.facebook.com/watch/?v=1885446134859076&_rdr)